# How to search for and return an item from an std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In my current situation I have a `std::vector` filled with `Vector3f` objects (each with x, y and z values) acting as mesh vertices, I want to get my player position (also a `Vector3f`) and send it to a function that can search for a mach in the `Vector3f` objects in the before mentioned mesh vertices vector and return the matched `Vector3f`, so that I can access its y component and use it to set the players height.

The closest I have gotten is the bellow:

```
Vector3f Mesh::checkMeshVertices(Vector3f playerPos)
{
    return std::find(meshVertices.begin(), meshVertices.end(), playerPos) != meshVertices.end();
}
```

However, this would just return true upon a match, I want to be able to return the actual `Vector3f` that was the match.

Comment: How familiar are you with iterators? Take a look at what [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns.

Comment: You're receiving by value and returning by value; if the `Vector3f` you passed doesn't already contain this information, your overload of `operator==` is kinda suspicious (it's willing to consider two vectors equal, even when they don't match on fairly critical state).

Comment: Question is what would you return if there is no match? Maybe the return type should be `std::optional<Vector3f>`?

Comment: "I want to be able to return the actual Vector3f that was the match." The function that calls this method already has the `Vector3f` object because it passed it in as `playerPos`.

Comment: Since the function returns a value that compares equal to `playerPos`, if the return type was `Vector3f` the function would be redundant. You probably want to change the return type to `bool`. Edit : Maybe you intend to return by reference? If so, the name of the function could be improved. Check implies the function's result is `true` or `false`.

Comment: *I want to be able to return the actual Vector3f that was the match.* -- And with no match?  Time to learn about [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: You can always use the old-fashioned method of a `for` loop, accessing `playerPos[i]`.

Comment: Does your `Vector3f` class have overloaded `operator==`?  Maybe you need to supply a custom search function to the `find` method.

Comment: Code-Apprentice is right, caller of your function *already has that vector*, because it's passing it to you as an argument, no reason to return it there. Checking if it is in vector (probably) makes more sense.

Comment: From the text I have the impression that there is no need for an exact match but instead matches are only based on x and z coordinates. If this isn't done with an `operator==` overload (and hopefully it isn't as it would be unexpected behavior for most developers) then `std::find_if(meshVertices.begin(), meshVertices.end(), [&](Vector3f pos){ return pos.x == playerPos.x && pos.z == playerPos.z; })` would be a better search.

Comment: @Kyle_Pearce you have some answers below. Provide us with some feedback (upvote answers which bring value and accept answer that helped you the most)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the return value is `bool` while the return type of the function is `Vector3f`.

As the returned type is not a referenced type then in case the vector is found you can use in the caller its passed argument. SO the function can just return a bool value like

```
bool Mesh::checkMeshVertices(Vector3f playerPos)
{
    return std::find(meshVertices.begin(), meshVertices.end(), playerPos) != meshVertices.end();
}
```

if you want to return a reference to the found object then the function should throw an exception in case when the object is not found.

For example

```
Vector3d & Mesh::checkMeshVertices(Vector3f playerPos)
{
    auto it = std::find(meshVertices.begin(), meshVertices.end(), playerPos);
    if ( it != meshVertices.end() ) return *it;
    else throw std::out_of_range();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can return both boolean value, that indicates success in finding the element, and the actual iterator to that specific element (or the value that's found) from your function. In order to achieve this, you should use C++17's feature called [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Here is a simple code which you can then apply to your case:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::pair<bool, std::vector<int>::const_iterator> find(std::vector<int> const& v, int number) {
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), number);
    if (v.end() == it) {
        return std::make_pair(false, it);
    }  else {
        return std::make_pair(true, it);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    if (auto [success, iter] = find(v, 5); success) {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMTO8ADqgWF1tPYYmZqRePmp0NnaORi5ukrxKKuG0DATMxAQBxqacisqYqn6p6QSRDs6uggppGVlBudUlZdGxXACUiqgGxMgcAORSAMy2yIZYANTigzoAbgVExFPY4gAMAIJDI2OYk9MGaqyEAJ5LqxuSw7SjBhNTOurVxJjMRqfrm1fbuzpswCSECFeg2W73W1XQIBAHmYeEW0ycqH0pHG4Mhc1UJDutgIS0haFo1QA%2BoRXMwFktxlRbOgIKiQOjydNsRT8dUpAA2cYzZHY8a0CrENqTADssnW4wl42Y%2B1Q40IuwAIiiCBCQFTtBAZgA6FzAWwQDpcrWWA3I/kxVxtKZitaSuVUcaa40aoVTBVuuUEV2is52u1PAjdWjK1VGZgAa0whOhsOobCUPK91t9kvEwqV42UShFNr9koDQZDkLDkejMOIEAIxAMmETVsGudT6bOafdoLWvLD%2Bu9jYldIZmKZ9ApM0VOfGuXG5nGg2RvHGAFYRe6GymJXgHRBpURJgvpAoDMhegoFInXOIF0qPeqadzF/XpCjD8eFD21366Wh9t87pNJJIADEum0KRJB/aYixASxWGTcUmyVLMdjTXsPxVPEugIcCdD/SR7FQTCaAMED/ywyDoNg214JbOCJQLYhgxWCjWz6DpWBAPoFz6UhTD6FYuNQdidDkOQUS6HokIuTguIIdi%2BLaDpwxAbgAE4tQADgXFTuHZQZBhWHhJE4dkhHY7guJ4vjSAEvouIUEAVlIGTeJY0g4FgGBEBQVAjA8PB2DICgIDQHy/MqYBlPMKlWAIVw7IgJxZK4pxbHSI52Kk0hgqMLQCAAeVoVg0uc0gsDDUR2ESkrYXmPA5js4rMAADwKfZ%2Bks7FlEqw4nGIVK9CwdLpOIPAjEGjoaHoJg2A4Hh%2BGCYRRBQYSZCEPAnDsyAOlQDxknqgBacE3QkGQ5E4YVbPyQoNAgSw6hyCxtGaAVBFCXw6Dul7vDe2gnotNwGku5JilqfRsiqQGihqUpbHKP6qihj6Gih37Wk4DoFDE3p2hMjjzMq6zGrU9k9vZbhxmAI9xlUsCIFwQgSD/QZJz0EL/MZyQhSEk6ZGkxL5NIRSFxWLUeCFhdBnZdllI04U1O4BccbM0hRqF7j8fY2z7McvnXI8iAkAwjx9nIShgt8/zgkwfAFkECbGBYCrZoAd16jwxpxzi1eK6yhjAp2AXGQnidJ8nKep3nnP5hBniwNxTTYvolZVhyLP4jXFC1py5IUkAhZF%2BWVnFyXpYXWX5ZxwY8e99Os5Y1j2MkKvLOsiPs9IOZiB8DRuCAA%3D%3D).

Applying this logic to your example would look like the following:

```cpp
std::pair<bool, std::vector<Vector3f>::const_iterator> Mesh::checkMeshVertices(Vector3f playerPos) {
    auto it = std::find(meshVertices.begin(), meshVertices.end(), playerPos);
    if (meshVertices.end() == it) {
        return std::make_pair(false, it);
    } else {
        return std::make_pair(true, it);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You could also use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <algorithm>

std::optional<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> find(std::vector<int> const& v, int number) {
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), number);
    if (v.end() == it) {
        return {}; // or return std::nullopt;
    }  else {
        return it;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto iter = find(v, 6);
    if (iter) {
        std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```